# gradle jacocoTestReport is not working?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have tried to get code coverage in a spring-gradle project using gradle jacoco plugin.

The build.gradle contains the following

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

I then ran

```
gradle test jacocoTestReport
```

Where after only the file test.exec is generated in build/reports folder.

Other than that nothing happens.

**How can I get the HTML report?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following helped . its in samples/testing/jacaco of gradle-2.3-all.zip from https://gradle.org/releases/

```
apply plugin: "java"

apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.+"
}

test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}


jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

Comment: check this as well - http://csiebler.github.io/blog/2014/02/09/multi-project-code-coverage-using-gradle-and-jacoco/

Comment: The syntax `html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"` is deprecated as of Gradle 4.9 and will be removed in Gradle 5.0. Use `html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")` instead.

Comment: append and classDumpFile are no longer supported with Gradle 6.

Comment: @Jakob Thanks a ton< this resolved the error for me

Answer (score 21):

## You don't have to configure `reportsDir/destinationFile`

Because jacoco has default values for them.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Run `gradle test jacocoTestReport`

You can find the test report in `./build/reports/jacoco/test` directory.

HTML output is in `./build/reports/jacoco/test/html` directory.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, none of these answers worked for me.

I had a similar issue.
Only different in not having the ***exec*** file generated.

And because of that ,
I found that the jacocoTestReport was simply "**skipped**".

**I got it fixed by adding** :

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

jacocoTestReport {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

That's because I'm using **Junit5 with spring boot 2.X**

Comment: In our case, the symptom was confusing: upgrading the Sonarqube server 7.x to 8.9 suddenly caused code coverage to stop working, even though we had all the correct XML report settings. It turns out our jacocoTestReport step had never been run by our pipelines, but Sonarqube v7 was quietly reading in the .exec code coverage file instead. v8 got rid of that file. So adding the `finalizedBy` statement above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprojects {
    apply(plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm')

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
   }
}

task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport) {

    // Gather execution data from all subprojects
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")

    // Add all relevant sourcesets from the subprojects
    subprojects.each {
        sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
}

// always run the tests before generating the report
codeCoverageReport.dependsOn {
    subprojects*.test
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "your_project_key"
        property "sonar.verbose", true
        property "sonar.projectName", "Your project name"
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "${rootDir}/build/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport/codeCoverageReport.xml"
    }
}
```

Command to run test with coverage:

```
./gradlew codeCoverageReport
./gradlew sonarqube -x test (test is excluded since already run and sonarqube by default executes test)
```

The second command can be ignored if sonarqube is not being used.

Two things to be noted that made it work:

1. To make available sourcesets of all modules, looping over subprojects and **accumulating sourcesets worked.** subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs did not work.
2. **sonar.jacoco.reportPaths** is **deprecated**. We need to use sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths. Check the documentation here

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle file using gradle 8.2

```
sonar {
  properties {
      property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
      property 'sonar.login', 
      'squ_b715dcf08655b02c3e32ae1ad0d6987ab239ec64'
      property 'sonar.verbose', true
      property 'sonar.qualitygate.wait', true
      property 'sonar.projectKey', 'sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage'
  }
}

jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
     xml.required = true
  }
}
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

tasks.named('sonar').configure {
 dependsOn test
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```