# Could not find method jacocoTestReport() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport, dependsOn=testDebugUnitTest}

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, jacoco

I am following along with this tutorial to try and get test coverage metrics in my java + kotlin project which is built with gradle :

[http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2017/12/20/how-to-configure-jacoco-for-kotlin-and-java-project/](http://Could%20not%20find%20method%20jacocoTestReport()%20for%20arguments%20[%7Btype=class%20org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport,%20dependsOn=testDebugUnitTest%7D)

I copy and pasted each block in, to avoid any syntax errors on my part - and am getting the following error :

```
Could not find method jacocoTestReport() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport, dependsOn=testDebugUnitTest}
```

The only thing I do differently from the tutorial is drop 'task' from the line which is the signature of jacocoTestReport... because if I have it - the plugin cries that the task cannot be added, as it is already defined - as per the documentation, I removed it - so that it extends the one provided by the plugin.

Has anyone else seen this? I could really use some help - as it wont work no matter what I do. Also, this is a straight java + kotlin project, not android.

Comment: Are you doing `apply plugin: Jacoco` at the correct project level or higher level build.gradle file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097393/gradle-jacocotestreport-is-not-working

Comment: or try changing that to `task jacocoTestReport(type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") << {
`

Comment: Take a look at my response here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372067/cannot-add-task-jacocotestreport-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-exists/49374833#49374833. I suspect that a newer version of the jacoco plugin now defines that task rather than relying on every build to define it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add task ':jacocoTestReport' as a task with that name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372067/cannot-add-task-jacocotestreport-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-exists)